# Model data sharing in rails using http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, soa

I have two rails app. Let's say `App1` and `App2`. `App1` has a model which is the core of my business and `App2` wanted to use that.

One approach I was thinking was to create `PORO` which mimics ActiveRecord functionality but instead of interacting with the DB, it will interact with `App1` over `HTTP` or `https`.

For example:

```
class User < NetworkRecord
  def self.find(id)
    new.find(id)
  end

  def find(id)
    endpoint = 'https:app1.com/user'
    get(endpoint, { id: id })
  end
end


class NetworkRecord
  def get(endpoint, params)
    Httparty.get(endpoint, params)
  end
end
```

I am not sure whether this approach is too intelligent or right, because we are giving some functionality of `ActiveModel` to an Object without inheriting from it.

If you know any better way to achieve the same thing, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you're thinking along the same lines as [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource), which provides an ActiveRecord-like interface to objects across a REST interface.

If you're intending to keep the two codebases entirely separate, then some form of API-based relationship is probably the way to go. One thing you do have to be careful with is how much network traffic you generate with this approach. If these two apps are going to be the only users of the API you build, you have an opportunity to build more customised endpoints based on your use cases that can deliver the data you need as efficiently as possible.

Comment: what do you mean by `you have an opportunity to build more customized endpoints based on your use cases that can deliver the data you need as efficiently as possible`?

Comment: Basically that you only need to transfer the information between applications that they need to get the job done. If you're doing actions on one app that require lots of individual REST calls to the other, you might be able to replace that with a single API call that places a request, and gets a tailored response. It really depends on your what your apps are doing, but the key is that if both of them under your control, and no other apps are going to need to use the same API that they use to talk to each other, you have options beyond REST.